Uploading file to custom backend from a jira plugin
I am trying to make a Jira plugin that can upload files. I am using my backend to handle the logic and it's working fine when I try that from the postman.
But when I try the same from Jira Plugin no form-data is going in the request.
I am using the forge and custom UI for the plugin. For file upload I am using S3 and multer on backend.
I have tried by creating a react component outside the plugin code and its working from there as well
Here is upload file code
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Plus from '../../../../../assets/icons/Plus';
import { invokeApiRemote } from '../../../../../services/invokeApi';
import { createAttachment } from '../../../../../services/apiConfig';

const FileUpload = ({ onUpload, enableDragAndDrop, entityType, entityId }) => {
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const fileInputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleDragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDragging(true);
  };

  const handleDragLeave = () => {
    setIsDragging(false);
  };

  const handleDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDragging(false);
    const files = Array.from(e.dataTransfer.files);
    handleFiles(files);
  };

  const handleFiles = async (files) => {
    console.log(files)
    const formData = new FormData();
    console.log('Files to upload:', files);

    files && files.map((file) => {
      formData.append('files', file);
    });

    formData.append('attachableType', entityType);
    formData.append('attachableId', entityId);
    console.log(formData)

    try {
      const response = await invokeApiRemote({
        config: createAttachment(),
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check',
        },
      });

      if (response) {
        console.log('Attachment created successfully:', response);
        // onUpload && onUpload(response);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating attachment:', error);
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };

  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const files = Array.from(e.target.files);
    handleFiles(files);
  };

  const handleChooseFiles = () => {
    fileInputRef.current.click();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {enableDragAndDrop ? (
        <div
          onDragOver={handleDragOver}
          onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
          onDrop={handleDrop}
          onClick={handleChooseFiles}
          style={{
            border: isDragging ? '2px dashed #007bff' : '2px dashed #cccccc',
            padding: '20px',
            textAlign: 'center',
            marginBottom: '20px',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            backgroundColor: isDragging ? '#f8f9fa' : 'transparent',
          }}>
          <p>Drag & drop or click to select files</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Button
          size="sm"
          variant=""
          className="me-2"
          onClick={handleChooseFiles}>
          <Plus /> Attach files
        </Button>
      )}
      <input
        type="file"
        multiple
        onChange={handleFileChange}
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        ref={fileInputRef}
      />
      {error && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FileUpload;


I have tried many things and gone through multiple blogs but didn't find the fix or the solution for doing this

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-use-AUI-file-upload/qaq-p/536601 this might help

No it doesn't work
